# Unable to define an output file with XlsxWriter in Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I now have the simplest test script I can imagine, but it won’t work according to the XlsxWriter instructions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Test.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")
```

Full error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-310-9c7e424c6d39>", line 1, in <module>
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Test.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")

  File "/Users/ernie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1725, in __init__
    self.book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path, **engine_kwargs)

  File "/Users/ernie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 68, in __init__
    super(Workbook, self).__init__()

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: Did you add `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')` and

`writer.save()`

Comment: Those are my next lines but I cannot get past the error on the writer statement.

Comment: Also, you need to specify Data frame before invoking the writer. Something like this `df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})`

Comment: I have a data frame previously specified for my data, but that doesn’t appear to have anything to do with setting up the ‘writer’ statement. Can you replicate this error? --- same error with the single quotes

Comment: I am not having a access to PC, so I can't replicate for now.

Answer (score 0):

This error apparently had something to do with the session where Spyder and Python were running. I exited the session completely, re initiated it, and the error disappeared. Something somehow got corrupted, but very strange.